# Push Notification to HTML5/Phonegap app?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

How would phonegap/html5 app handle push notification.  Would it be same code or Android/iPhone? Does this work for phonegap based app on iOS and Android and are there any limitations?

Comment: Good idea to post why you are - this question.

Comment: is it easier to click a button or answer the question, ponder that.

Answer (score 1):

> How would phonegap/html5 app handle push notification

You can't handle the push notification in html, but you can in Java or Objective-C

> Would it be same code or Android/iPhone?

No, it won't. Push notification works quite the same way on Android and iOS but there are a few differences. Plus, because it is the native side of your PhoneGap application that will handle notifications, you will need to write different methods in both Java and Objective-C

> Does this work for phonegap based app on iOS and Android and are there any limitations?

I'm currently working on a PhoneGap application on iOS and Android and push notification works fine on both these OS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [UrbanAirship](http://www.urbanairship.com):

- https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-phonegap-plugin
- http://minimoesfuerzo.org/2011/06/6/urban-airship-10-integration-android-phonegap-app/

Comment: Could you please state some of the advantages of UrbanAirship for Android vs. OpenMobster?  Why do you recommend it?

Answer (score 0):

I am just now in the process of developing the PhoneGap plugin for OpenMobster. From the looks of it for OpenMobster, the Push notification code with its corresponding Broadcast listeners will remain the same as in the pure native app development. On iOS as well there should be no added PhoneGap specific code required to handle the Push notifications via the Apple Push Notification Service.

To answer your question, in theory the html5/javascript codebase using PhoneGap should remain the same for both the platforms.

(p.s. this applies to how OpenMobster handles push notification. I am not sure how Urban Airship handles the PhoneGap side of things)

Thanks
Sohil